# CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE old_table_name with old_table_name's AUTO_INCREMENT values

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sql-like, create-table

Can I create a new table with an old table's autoincriment status in mysql client?

I think, that `ALTER TABLE new_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=@my_autoincr_iment` helps me, but this construction must use with a constant value.
I don't want to use a difficult script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mysql> `create table new_table like old_table;`

mysql> `select @my_auto_increment:=auto_increment from information_schema.tables where table_name='old_table';`

mysql> `set @query = CONCAT("alter table new_table auto_increment = ", @my_auto_increment);`

mysql> `prepare stmt from @query;`

mysql> `execute stmt;`

mysql> `deallocate prepare stmt;`

Thx to my brother!

Answer (score 0):

Your CREATE TABLE can specify the auto_increment to use:

```
mysql> create table foo (i int primary key auto_increment, s varchar(12)) auto_increment = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (s) values ("s");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| i  | s    |
+----+------+
| 10 | s    |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: I don't know, how post mysql's syntax. Your exemple is't suitable.

Comment: mysql> `set @my_auto_increment=555;`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> `select @my_auto_increment;`
+--------------------+ | @my_auto_increment | +--------------------+ | 555 |
+--------------------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> `ALTER TABLE zz AUTO_INCREMENT=@my_auto_increment;`
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@my_auto_increment' at line 1

Comment: The questioner wants to create new table using the LIKE clause. This is usually the case when you need to create multiple tables (like archiving huge data set) where providing individual auto_increment values and table definitions is not practical.